# How can I fill a GridView in WPF with queries from a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, gridview

I am working on a project using VS2010, WPF, and C#.

I used SQL Server 2008 to build a database for my project , and I imported my (.mdf) file to my project.

In my project I have a GridView that has 2 columns ( text column - checkBox column)

Let's say that I queried on my database and my query returned 5 words. I want these words to appear as rows in the GridView with a checkBox next to each one of them.

Do you know how I can do this?! Because I tried but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. But if you bind the Grid to a collection of objects with a `string` and a `bool` property you will get the desired result. So you can project the data from the database into a collection of the appropriate type and you will get the result.

Here is a simple example, I have not bothered with all the property notification etc. First want to confirm that this is what you are after.

XAML - Binding the DataGrid to a `Data` property int he code behind.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfTest
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Data { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      // Setup the data context to refer to this object
      // depending on your design, this might all be in a ViewModel
      // of sorts
      DataContext = this;

      // Imagine this data was loaded from the database and populated into the
      // Data collection
      Data = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
      Data.Add(new DataItem() { Word = "Word 1", Checked = false });
      Data.Add(new DataItem() { Word = "Word 2", Checked = false });
      Data.Add(new DataItem() { Word = "Word 3", Checked = true });
      Data.Add(new DataItem() { Word = "Word 4", Checked = false });
      Data.Add(new DataItem() { Word = "Word 5", Checked = true });
    }    
  }

  public class DataItem
  {
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
  }
}
```